# Proper way to unsubscribeCrosshairMove handler in lightweight charts

Tags: javascript, lightweight-charts

According to the [docs](https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/docs/api/interfaces/IChartApi#unsubscribecrosshairmove), `unsubscribeCrosshairMove` is used to unsubscribe a handler that was previously subscribed using `subscribeCrosshairMove`. We intend to use `unsubscribe...` to remove previous handlers before using `subscribe...` to re-subscribe the crosshair move after seriesData updates. The code below, however does not properly unsubscribe, I assume because of the syntax used in `subscribe...` to access the `e` event. Does anyone know how to preserve the `e` for event data access, while also enabling `unsubscribe...`? #tradingview

```
this.mainChart.unsubscribeCrosshairMove(this.subCrossAndSync());
this.mainChart.subscribeCrosshairMove((e) => this.subCrossAndSync(e, this.midChart, seriesData));
```

Answer (score 2):

**You shouldn't be using the arrow function syntax directly inside the subscribe method.**

You need to keep a reference to the handler function which you pass to subscribe...(), so that you can provide that **same** reference to unsubscribe...() method.

There are a few ways to do this. Perhaps you could assign the handler to a variable first and then pass that variable to the subscribe method.

```js
const handlerOne = (e) => {
 console.log('1', e);
};
chart.subscribeCrosshairMove(handlerOne);
chart.unsubscribeCrosshairMove(handlerOne);
```

An example: https://jsfiddle.net/msilverwood/20oser5f/

Comment: Is there any way to pass arguments in ˙handlerOne`? You can see I am passing e, this.mainChart, and seriesData into subCrossAndSync() -- it seems these would need to be passed through handlerOne too

Comment: In this case, the handler function is using the arrow function syntax `=>` which means it has access to the scope in which it is defined. [arrow-functions](https://javascript.info/arrow-functions) You can use that to pass those other variables to your function of choice...  
const seriesData = [1,2,3];
const handlerOne = (e) => {
 this.yourHandler(e, seriesData);
};

Comment: Thanks, @SlicedSilver. A new requirement has me wondering: What if you wanted to pass `this.mainChart` (from `this.mainChart.subscribeCrosshairMove(handlerOne)` through to the handler function? Is it accessible via the `e` event, or would including it as an argument such as in `this.mainChart.subscribeCrosshairMove(handlerOne(e,this.mainChart))` maintain unsubscribability?